# How to run github action workflow in a pull request with the content from the respective repository

Tags: github, github-actions

I have github workflow file as follows.

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{github.head_ref}}
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: Builde
      run: docker build -t <tag-name> .
```

In `Dockerfile` I'm copying the content of the repository in to the image in order to build it.
I'm using following for it.

```
COPY . target/
```

This workflow works fine to the pull requests which are tiggered from same repository. But when it is from a fork repository it fails.

I think I might get this working by providing `repository` argument as following in the checkout.

```yaml
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{github.head_ref}}
        fetch-depth: 0
        repository: //some thing here
```

But, I didn't find suitable value for it from here.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Is there any way to get this working?.

**Edit:**

The checkout action fails since the branch which used to open the PR is not in the base repo.
Including screenshot for clarity.
`myurud/jasminegraph` is the target repository for the PR. And I'm opening the PR from my own fork's `fix-docker-build` branch.
[image]

Comment: Which step fails?

Comment: @Azeem The `checkout` action in base repository.

Comment: What is the error? Please include that error in your question for clarity. BTW, did you try pushing directly to the repo instead of creating a PR? As `github.head_ref` is only available for PR related events i.e. `pull_request` and `pull_request_target`, your direct pushes should fail too.

Comment: @Azeem edited question with more information. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by specifying the `repository` to `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name || github.repository }}` in the action checkout.